# Custom Paypal Cart (Payment ID Number)

Tags: php, paypal, cron, shopping-cart, cart

We are working on finding a solution for a custom PayPal cart install. I'll try to explain what actions are taking place then point out where we are having issues.

Here is the issue that we are facing:

1.) Users of our site can purchase a subscription

2.) That subscription once paid for activates several actions on the user’s account.

3.) Subscriptions last for Xx amount of time.

4.) Each hour our cron page runs and checks for payment received or not.

5.) After Xx amount of time (the subscription length duration) if the payment is verified to have been received the users account automatically renews. If payment is not verified to have been received then the account we return to normal.

6.) We have it operating correctly in the scenario if the payment is made from one PayPal account for a single user subscription.

7.) However, if a user uses one PayPal account to purchase multiple subscriptions (for this example 10) and cancels X amount (for this example 9) of subscriptions from within their PayPal account, none of the accounts get cancelled from within our site. Say a office manager submits payment from one single PayPal account (because they are in charge of 10 users accounts). Then immediately cancels 9 of the subscriptions from within that sign PayPal account and leaves one active account in our current setup it still thinks a payment was received for all 10 of the users because it’s checking the account rather than individual PayPal subscription for payment. (Tricky to explain)

** What I am are trying to figure out is how to have this action record the Payment ID # that is given by PayPal for each individual subscription when a purchase is completed and when the cron page runs it would pair the user’s (our site user) account to their Payment ID # and take action accordingly. So this way if 9 of the payment ids did not receive a renewal payment those accounts would become inactive and the one payment ID subscription that did receive payment would active properly.

I hope that makes sense and I would really appreciate anyone's help on this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) to handle automated updates based on actions that occur on the PayPal account including new profiles, payments, failed payments, canceled profiles, etc.

Any time a transaction occurs on your account (payments, profiles, refunds, disputes, etc.) PayPal's server will POST all of the transaction data to a listener script you have sitting on your server.  Within your script you can process that data however you need to, and it happens in real-time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I assume this is just for gathering the information from paypal then I would need to create an action to active and inactive upgrades to our account holders depending on whether the user renews or cancels their subscription, correct.

Comment: Yes, the IPN details would give you all the data you would need to update your own system accordingly, send out email notifications, etc.

Comment: We are still having some issues with this. The problem lays only with one area. If a single paypal user purchases multiple subscriptions and cancels a percentage of them and leaves the other active it for some reason is not pairing up with the provided "Profile ID's" correctly. Here is a link to another question on this is being asked by our developer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466925/paypal-subscription-not-working-properly-when-one-account-has-been-used-for-two  - Really appreciate any help to get this resolved. Thanks