# PayPal subscription not working properly when one account has been used for two users

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, subscription

We have tested with a personal account in sandbox and live for three users for paypal subscription.After purchasing three subscription we cancelled one of them and continue with other two.So after one day, two of those should renew the subscription and continue and another one should not renew.For example those three accounts are A(purchase time: 4apr 2.30pm ),B(purchase time: 4apr 3pm),C(purchase time: 4apr 3.30pm,cancel time:4apr 3.45pm). Say we have cancelled account C. So on 5 apr at 2.30 pm A should renew,at 3 pm B should renew and 3.30pm C should cancel.But the problem we are facing is that those renew and cancellation process are not happening at the correct time.A is not renewed at exact 5apr 2.30pm. B is not renewed at exact 5apr 3pm.C is not cancelled at exact 5apr 3.30pm.All those actions are fired around 5apr 4.30pm(which is not right).So that is an time error.We set notify url in the paypal form and also in the business account for renewal functionality in database.
Here is the paypal form which we are using.

Note: We have used a single paypal account for all those three users.

So if any one have a solution for this please post here.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal doesn't guarantee that subscription payments will happen at a particular time of day -- only that they will happen on the day that they're supposed to.  Likewise, it's virtually impossible to predict exactly what time a subscription payment will take place.

If you need payments to happen at a particular time of day, you might consider establishing a billing agreement with the buyer and running a reference transaction against the billing agreement at the proper time.  More information on billing agreements is available here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/